# Regex find last body tag

Tags: javascript, regex

I know that a parser would best be suited for this situation but in my current situation it has to be just straight javascript.

I have a regex to find the closing body tag of an html doc.

```
var closing_body_tag = /(<\/body>)/i;
```

However, this fails when source has more than 1 body tag set. So I was thinking about going with something like this..

```
var last_closing_body_tag = /(<\/body>)$/gmi;
```

This works for the case when multiple tags are found, but for some reason it is failing on cases with just 1 set of  tags.

Am I making a mistake that would cause mixed results for single tag cases?

Yes, I understand more than one body tag is incorrect, however, we have to handle all bad source.

Comment: And why would you have more than one body tag ?

Comment: Just curious. Why do you need to find the closing body tag? What are you going to do with that?

Comment: You don't need jQuery for parsing HTML.

Comment: @adeneo The internet is a mysterious place full of people with bad decisions.  It is just a use case we have to handle, correct or incorrect.

Comment: @hindmost We insert a tag right before the last closing body tag.

Comment: `/^[\S\s]+(<\/body>)/i` does that work?

Comment: @Adam You don't need Regexp for that. Use DOM manipulation methods instead

Comment: The second expression should match only when the </body> tag is at the very end of the string, though I imagine you will usually have a </html> after that.

It would be very helpful if you could give some example input to demonstrate what's succeeding and what's failing.

Comment: `while (m=body_re.exec(text)): match next else last tag is the last matched`

Comment: @hindmost Can you give an example?

Comment: `document.body.appendChild` inserts an element right before the closing tag. A regex does not ?

Comment: More than 1 body tag???

Comment: @Adam Simple example (IE9+): `var elements = document.querySelectorAll('body'); if (elements.length) elements[elements.length-1].appendChild(document.createElement('your_tag'));`

Comment: Who says more than one body tag is incorrect? There's nothing wrong with having one <body> start tag and one </body> end tag provided everything is in the correct order. Having two body *elements* with or without their own tags, on the other hand...

Comment: [You can't parse (X)HTML with regex.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1529630)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
  /<\/body>(?![\s\S]*<\/body>[\s\S]*$)/i
```

`(?![\s\S]*<\/body>[\s\S]*$)` is a lookahead that ensures there is no more closing body tag before the end of the string.

Here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/kB8yV8/2).

Sample code for adding a tag:

```
var re = /<\/body>(?![\s\S]*<\/body>[\s\S]*$)/i; 
var str = '<html>\n<body>\n</body>\n</html>\n<html>\n<body>\n</body>\n</html>';
var subst = '<tag/>'; 
var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```

Comment: Maybe it's just my parser, but I get an error saying that lookaheads have to be zero-width.

Comment: When trying to use this in Javascript I am getting an error. Invalid regular expression: /(?i)<\/body>(?![\s\S]*<\/body>[\s\S]*$)/: Invalid group

Comment: Please check with my update. Inline option was a problem I guess

Answer (score 1):

## RegExp

As I suggested in the comments, use:

```
/^[\S\s]+(<\/body>)/i
```

#### How

This will get all text (greedy) until the text `</body>` the flag `i` means case-insensitive. This will work no matter how many body tags you have

```
</body>
</BODY>
</BoDY>
</body><!--This one's selected-->
```

You said you were using JavaScript which can be used as:

```
yourString.match(/^[\S\s]+(<\/body>)/i)[1];
```

`.match` works fine when you don't have the `g` flag. To further explain this RegExp

#### Explanation

> `^` Matches it at the beginning of the *whole* string because we don't have the `m` flag
>
> `[\S\s]+` will match *everything* until the following. **The `+` can be replaced by a `*`**
>
> `(<\/body>)` will get the body tag after the previous *(the last one)* and add it as a match
>
> `i` the `i` flag makes the string case-insensitive *(remove if you want it to be case sensitive)*

## JavaScript appendChild

If you have multiple body tags, you can still add an element before it.

```
var elem = document.createElement('div');
elem.setAttribute('id', 'mydiv');
elem.innerHTML = 'Foo';
```

Now, `elem` can be added in multiple ways:

#### 1:

```
window.document.body.appenedChild(elem);
```

#### 2:

```
var body_elems = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
body_elems[body_elems.length - 1].appendChild(elem);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
/(.|[\r\n])*(<\/body>)/mi
```

as a regexp. Capture group is $2.

This exploits greedy matching in connection with the multiline option. Note that the 'any char' symbol does not match newlines/carriage returns, which thus need explicit referral.

Comment: For the record, if you don't want to have two capture groups, you can insert `?:` just after the first `(` to make it a non-capturing group.

Answer (score 0):

The regex to match the last body tag is fairly simple:

```
/[\s\S]*(</body>)/i
```

What this does is match as many possible of *any character* (more specifically, any whitespacespace or anything that's not whitespace) before `</body>`.

The `i` flag means that it'll match any case for `</body>`, so anything like:

```
</body>
</BODY>
</BodY>
```

Will all match.

I used `[\s\S]` instead of `.` because `.` matches everything *but* the newline operators, which probably isn't what you want. `\s` matches all whitespace -- spaces, tabs, every kind of newline -- and `\S` is equivalent to `[^\s]`, so it matches everything that isn't whitespace. Together, these match every possible character. I'd imagine a similar thing is possible with `\w\W`, `\d\D`, etc., but `\s\S` is my preference.